# HttpUrlConnection must be declared every time?

Tags: java, android, http, network-programming

## 1

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/network_test.php");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes("some data to send");
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // prepare request to server

        // ...

        // recive data from server

        connection.disconnect();
    }
```

## 2

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/network_test.php");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes("some data to send");
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();


        // prepare request to server

        // ...

        // recive data from server
    }

connection.disconnect();
```

First options work perfect!

But why i can't use #2 version? Every time I must create new object HttpUrlConnection? Why?

Error at #2 version:

> java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write request body after response has been read

Answer (score 1):

> Instances of URLConnection are not reusable: you must use a different instance for each connection to a resource
>
> -- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: So, i create new HttpUrlConnection i Send and i create ... i send ... . And over and over again ... Thanks :)

Comment: You could reuse the URL.

Comment: The URL i know that.